# Are there other ways to visualize data not by graphing or tables?

Tags: data-visualization

I want to try something new with data visualization, where I can't use graphs, charts, or even tables to represent some data.

First, I will use a table to show some statistics.

| House No. | Energy Consumed | Bill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 kW | \$125.00 |
| 2 | 24 kW | \$120.00 |
| 3 | 31 kW | \$155.00 |
| 4 | 27 kW | \$135.00 |
| 5 | 36 kW | \$180.00 |
| 6 | 19 kW | \$95.00 |

And now we should try and recreate the data without a graph or a table. What I'm thinking for the visualizing is placing the data at something that can be visible or meant to be seen and doesn't have to be vocal.

What ways can we visualize this without the use of a graph or a table?

Comment: I would think out of the box at some music/tune representation of this association...

Comment: Could you give us any example of a "visualization" -- literally, something *meant to be seen* -- that could not reasonably be considered a "graph or table"?  Then we might know what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I am slightly confused by the question as I consider anything visual a type of graph. However, do you mean, using infographics? If so, there are various types you can consider. See [here](https://www.easel.ly/blog/types-of-infographics/) and [here](https://visme.co/blog/types-of-infographics/)

Other possibilities included using forms of art such as [Dance your PhD](https://www.sciencemag.org/projects/dance-your-phd).

If these are not helpful, could you say more about the intended audience and reasoning for wanting to use something other than a chart or graph?